# How to deploy webconfig changes alone in IIS/Azure?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, tfs, web-config

Currently, I've configured my CICD for WebAPI Project using TFS. So far so good. I also created separate web.config for every environments (`web.DEV.config`,`web.QA.config`,`web.PROD.config`)

**VS Build in TFS**

[image]

**Questions**

Sometimes we have to change only the configuration for QA environment. In such cases, we have to build the entire project (After changing the `web.QA.Config` file alone) which is not needed, we just need to deploy the new config to the QA. For now, we are deploying manually going into Azure App Service Editor/FTP to source code.

**Is there anyway if a configuration is changed only deploy the configurations alone instead of full CICD?**

Comment: What's the last step of your CD today? How did you publish to Azure? What I did is to build a master repo with source code repo(s) and deployment repo(s) as submodules, https://blog.lextudio.com/ci-cd-pipeline-with-vsts-and-zapier-b81d341088dd Then in my pipeline, use triggers from submodules to kick off all the builds and deployment to Azure. As the deployment repo is on its own, I can always manually edit `web.config` there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot be configured to achieve the feature directly. But you can consider to use some workaround. For exmaple:

1. Add a variable to your build definition like "FullBuild" with value "True".
2. Add a Powershell script task at the begin of your build definition. The powershell script will do the following:

   - Get the changeset/commit in the build to check which files are changed.
   - Update the "FullBuild" variable to "false" if only web.QA.Config is changed.
3. Set the original full build tasks to run with "Custom conditions": `and(succeeded(), eq(variables['FullBuild'], 'True'))`
4. Add some tasks to transform the web.config file and deploy the file to Azure with "Custom conditions": `and(succeeded(), eq(variables['FullBuild'], 'False'))`

To transform the web.config file, you can create your customer powershell script to do it or use some build tasks like: [Apply transformations](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jungeriusit.jungit-apply-transformations).

Answer (score 0):

You can change your Web Apps settings directly in Azure without a deployment. This will work for your situation because future deployments will not override whatever you configure via the portal, i.e., it's a one time process.

[image]

Comment: This can be possible, but this again a manual changes. I do really want the config changes to check-in my repo